# IE6 scroll event not working inside Iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-6, scroll

So here is our scenario...
We have a old website and from that website,on click of a button, we launch our newly developed application from within an IFrame.
Now In IE6 , I am trying to catch the scroll event (ie catch the scroll of the browser).
However,it dosent either the event isnt getting fired or i am not tapping into the right object.
The strange thing is that I am able to catch the event if we directly open our new website  and do not come from the old website.So this points towards the IFrame as being teh culprit...but I am still not able to figure this out

We use jquery so I tried..
a) $(window).scroll
b) $(window.parent).scroll
c) $(window.parent.window).scroll
d) $(window.top).scroll

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Can you provide sample markup/code showing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes jQuery has problems firing the event if top level parent elements have their css overflow property set to anything other than auto.